# Replica in SYNC WITH TIMEOUT returns 0 for TIMEOUT

Tags: memgraphdb

I have Memgraph 2.2.0 (Docker using memgraph-platform image) running on Windows based computer.

When registering a REPLICA instance with the SYNC WITH TIMEOUT mode, then showing REPLICA instances' details, the TIMEOUT for that instance is 0.

Here is what I've done:

- created to Memgraph instances
- set one to be REPLICA
- registered REPLICA using `REGISTER REPLICA REP2 SYNC WITH TIMEOUT 1 TO "192.168.0.10";`
- checked the status of replicas with `SHOW REPLICAS`

In the result I can see that the TIMEOUT for REP2 is 0. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/pull/376), and fix was included in Memgraph 2.3.1.